# Facing Issue in zend_search_lucene

Tags: zend-framework, zend-lucene

I am using Zend Lucene Search:

```
    ......
    $results = $test->fetchAll();

                   setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'de_DE.iso-8859-1');
          Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8());
                foreach ($results as $result) {
                    $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();

                    // add Fields
                    $doc->addField(
                            Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('testid', $result->id));
                    $doc->addField(
                            Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('testemail', strtolower(($result->email))));
                    $doc->addField(
                            Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('testconfirmdate', $result->confirmdate));
                    $doc->addField(
                            Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('testcreateddate', $result->createddate));
                    // Add document to the index
                    $index->addDocument($doc);
                }
                // Optimize index.
                $index->optimize();

                // Search by query
                setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'de_DE.iso-8859-1');
                if(strlen($Data['name']) > 2){
                    //$query = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::parse($Data['name'].'*');
                                    $pattern = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($Data['name'].'*');
                                    $query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard($pattern);
                                    $this->view->hits = $index->find(strtolower($query));
                            }
                else{
                    $query  = $Data['name'];
                                    $this->view->hits = $index->find($query);
                                }
............
```

Works fine here:

1. It works when I give complete word, first 3 character, case insensitive words

My issues are:

1. When I search for email, i got error like "`Wildcard search is supported only for non-multiple word terms` "
2. When I search for number/date like "`1234`" or `09/06/2011`, I got error like "At least 3 non-wildcard characters are required at the beginning of pattern"

I want to search date, email, number here.

Answer (score 0):

In file zend/search/Lucene/search/search/query/wildcard a parameter is set,

```
private static $_minPrefixLength = 3;
```

chnage it and it may work..!

Answer (score 0):

Based on NaanuManu's suggestion, I did a little more digging to figure this out - I posted my answer on a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14187263/1319066), but repeating for convenience:

Taken directly from the [Zend Reference documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.query-language.html#zend.search.lucene.query-language.wildcard), you can use:

- `Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard::getMinPrefixLength()` to
  query the minimum required prefix length and
- use `Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard::setMinPrefixLength()` to
  set it.

So my suggestion would be either of two things:

1. Set the prefixMinLength to 0 using `Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard::setMinPrefixLength(0)`
2. Validate all search queries using javascript or otherwise to ensure there is a minimum of `Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard::getMinPrefixLength()` before any wildcards used (I recommend querying that instead of assuming the default of "3" so the validation is flexible)